# Identification of cloudy days based on Net Radiation data

Tags: remote-sensing, climate, atmospheric-correction, solar-radiation

How can I identify that a particular day is cloudy or clear sky based on the daily time series of Net Radiation (calculated at FluxNet/AMERIFlux sites)? I read somewhere that clear sky radiation has sinusoidal behavior. If we get different behavior that means it is induced by clouds. I don't know how exactly approach this problem? Here is the sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1YfWgPbg3fxhFG1DTNH9Ex3lTDqLBZp/view?usp=sharing